# How to make a sprite moving at the same speed of tileSprite in Phaser3

Tags: phaser-framework

I am new in Phaser.
I want to make a background which represent the ground moving and there should be a bunch of rocks above it which I made them as a sprite group.

I made the ground as a `tileSprite`, and on each update I changed the `tilePositionX`. my problem is how to set the velocity of the rocks to match the update in the background so they appear to be on the ground and moving at the same speed of the ground.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: you can check the code of winner_joiner, it is exactly the same method I did, hope to find another way as this is not efficient with old browsers. thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

theoretically you could measure the passed time, from the last `update` function call, and calculate the difference, or just eye-ball the needed velocity. *(aka. try different velocities until it matches up with the background-movement)*:

***Update**:*
*If no physics object is needed you could move the "rock" "manually", this is very easy.*

**Here a quick demo, that I *eye-balled*:**

- *The red mushroom, uses physics and velocity*. **Warning:** the speed of the object can/will vary depending on the browser and hardware.
- ***Update**: The green mushroom, is moved manually via the position.*

```js
// Minor formating for stackoverflow
document.body.style = "display: flex;flex-direction: column;";    

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 150,
    physics:{
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: { debug: true }
    },
    scene: {
         preload,
         create,
         update
    }
}; 

var tilesprite;
var redRock;
var greenRock;

function preload ()
{
    this.load.image('mushroom', 'https://labs.phaser.io/assets/sprites/mushroom16x16.png');
}

function create ()
{
    tilesprite = this.add.tileSprite(400, 300, 800, 600, 'mushroom');

    redRock = this.add.image(400, 40, 'mushroom').setScale(2);
    redRock.setTint(0xff0000);

    this.physics.add.existing(redRock);
    redRock.body.setVelocityX(-60)

    greenRock = this.add.image(400, 90, 'mushroom').setScale(2);
    greenRock.setTint(0x00ff00);

}

function update (time, delta){
    tilesprite.tilePositionX += 1;
    
    let speedCorrection = (1000/60)/delta;
    redRock.body.setVelocityX(-60 * speedCorrection )

    greenRock.x -= 1;
    
    // extra "reset" Rock
    if( redRock.x + 16 < 0 ){
      redRock.x = this.sys.game.canvas.width + 16;
      greenRock.x = this.sys.game.canvas.width + 16;
    }
}


var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.min.js">
</script>
```

> **Disclaimer:** It is not the most elegant solution, but it took me literally 30 Seconds to find a matching velocity.

**Minor Update:**
I improved the *eye-ball-method* with a speed correction, it can cause minor flickering/slipping(max 1-2 pixel skips), but should move constant on *"all"* device.

The change is just adding a small calculation `let speedCorrection = (1000/60)/delta;`

Comment: thank you for your answer, the eye-ball method for the red mushrooms is what I did, the problem is with older browser and low FPS the rock appears flickering and not steady, my game should support all browser even those on old phones.

Comment: @Luhaib-j thank you for the feedback, I updated the eye-ball mehtod, it should compensate for the FPS drops, but should _flicker_ less (or not) due to pixel-rounding. just if you want to try a different mehtod.